# How I replace a word with • but show only de first and the last character

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql

Replace a word with a symbol in oracle but let the first and the last character.

I tried `REGEXP_REPLACE('ANNE MARRY', '(\w)\w', '\1*')`

I want when I introduce "Anne Marry" my query return "A••e M•••y"

It's the `REGEXP_REPLACE` the solution?

Answer (score 3):

Oracle does not support the syntax necessary to solve this using a single regular expression.

You can do it without regular expressions using simple string functions and a recursive sub-query:

```sql
WITH replacements (id, value, epos) AS (
  SELECT ROWNUM, value, 1 FROM table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         CASE
         WHEN INSTR(value, ' ', epos) = 0 AND epos <= LENGTH(value) - 2
         THEN SUBSTR(value, 1, epos)
              || LPAD('•', LENGTH(value) - epos - 1, '•')
              || SUBSTR(value, -1)
         WHEN INSTR(value, ' ', epos) <= epos + 2
         THEN value
         ELSE SUBSTR(value, 1, epos)
              || LPAD('•', INSTR(value, ' ', epos) - epos - 2, '•')
              || SUBSTR(value, INSTR(value, ' ', epos) - 1)
         END,
         INSTR(value, ' ', epos) + 1
  FROM   replacements
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY id SET order_id
CYCLE id, epos SET is_cycle TO 1 DEFAULT 0
SELECT value
FROM   replacements
WHERE  is_cycle = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
  SELECT 'ANNE MARRY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'XI NG' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A B C D E' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'MAY' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| VALUE |
| --- |
| A••E M•••Y |
| XI NG |
| A B C D E |
| M•Y |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iwMqnqAA)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which regex engine is used in *Oracle* but if you can use
negative lookbehind and lookahead then you can match any word character
which isn't preceded or followed by a word boundary. In JavaScript, you
could use this pattern:

```
/(?<!\b)\w(?!\b)/g
```

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/N7yJDP/1

Or run it here:

```js
const regex = /(?<!\b)\w(?!\b)/g;
const input = `Annie Marry is probably a cook`;
const substitution = `•`;

const result = input.replace(regex, substitution);

console.log('result: ', result);
```

Comment: AFAIK Oracle regex doesn't support lookarounds (nor `\K`). You can check your attempts [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/d4rpHUdl)

Comment: Thanks @markalex for the info and the link! I see that quite a lot of DB engines have relatively old regex engines and it's rather frustrating that they don't upgrade them.

Comment: I believe this situation can also be caused (at least partially) by the fact, that lookarounds are quite performance "heavy". This might be not that important for single use regexes, but applying it to every row could make rather significant dent on query performance in general.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar by using a view to show the masked data and a trigger

Below are my steps.

```
CREATE TABLE CARDS_TBL (
  CARD_ID NUMBER
    GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  CARD_STR VARCHAR2(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (CARD_ID)
);

INSERT INTO CARDS_TBL(CARD_STR) VALUES('4024007187788590');
INSERT INTO CARDS_TBL(CARD_STR) VALUES('5432223398564536');
INSERT INTO CARDS_TBL(CARD_STR) VALUES('5430445512530934');
INSERT INTO CARDS_TBL(CARD_STR) VALUES('4020156755227854');
INSERT INTO CARDS_TBL(CARD_STR) VALUES('5431248766892318');


CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW CARDS AS
  SELECT
    CARD_ID,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(CARD_STR, 
'(\w)(\w*(\w))?', '\1**********\3') AS CARD_STR
  FROM CARDS_TBL;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CARDS_TBL_TRG_INSERT
  INSTEAD OF INSERT ON CARDS 
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO CARDS_TBL (CARD_STR) VALUES (:NEW.CARD_STR);
END;
/

INSERT INTO CARDS_TBL (CARD_STR) VALUES ('2222333344445555');

SELECT * FROM CARDS_TBL;

CARD_ID CARD_STR
1   4024007187788590
2   5432223398564536
3   5430445512530934
4   4020156755227854
5   5431248766892318
21  2222333344445555

UPDATE CARDS_TBL 
  SET CARD_STR = '2222333344445566'
  WHERE CARD_ID = 5;
/

SELECT * FROM CARDS;

CARD_ID CARD_STR
1   4**********0
2   5**********6
3   5**********4
4   4**********4
5   2**********6
21  2**********5


SELECT * FROM CARDS_TBL;

CARD_ID CARD_STR
1   4024007187788590
2   5432223398564536
3   5430445512530934
4   4020156755227854
5   2222333344445566
21  2222333344445555
```

Comment: This will work only if input has fixed length or it is acceptable to generate output with same length in masking. Example form the question will be converted to `A**********e M**********y`.

Comment: Thanks for the update. As per my example, we mask credit cards and it was decided to make the output the same length so it's more difficult to guess the number of characters for each card. As you pointed out this may not what the OP wanted.

Comment: @markalex if the user doesn't want fixed length masked output they can use regexp_replace(CARD_STR, '(^.)?.(.$)?', '\1*\2') AS CARD_STR

Comment: This will work only if input doesn't have spaces. Similar idea `regexp_replace('ANNE MARRY', '(^.|\s.)?.(.$|.\s)?', '\1*\2')` [almost works](https://dbfiddle.uk/zKCJ1nhR), but impossibility of double matching of space prevents saving first letter of second and following words.

Comment: 1. [Stack Overflow (Stack Exchange, in the more general sense) is not a forum.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115) 2. I don't believe this answer deserves to be upvote, let alone accepted: It is basically block of code with no explanation what or why is done, and no explanation how this block is related to question at hand. Moreover, only related to question part is a select with `REGEXP_REPLACE`, and it is not clearly separated from setup and demo.